# NuGet release notes

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, nuget

I added Property to include Package release note, but I don't see it in Nuget and visual studio Nuget Package manager.  Anyone noticed this ?

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <IncludeSymbols>true</IncludeSymbols>
    <SymbolPackageFormat>snupkg</SymbolPackageFormat>
    <PackageLicenseExpression>MIT</PackageLicenseExpression>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <PackageReleaseNotes>Testing</PackageReleaseNotes>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Hi Yassir, thank you for your question. You need to be more detailed with your question. What have you tried? Are you getting any errors? What can you tell us about the environment? Consider updating your answer with more information.

Comment: I'm working on a .Net Core library and I'm generating a NuGet package on build.  When I publish the generated package in NuGet.org, I can see all information I added in the .csproj like Authors, Description, Copyright..etc, But I don't see Release notes even I have set the PackageReleaseNotes property.

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT.  Yes your solution worked and this is exactly what I have done except for I was reading release notes from a file, and it turned out that I had the path for the file wrong. I fixed the Path and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to modify the author, description,copyright, you have to use these properties:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <IncludeSymbols>true</IncludeSymbols>
    <SymbolPackageFormat>snupkg</SymbolPackageFormat>
    <PackageLicenseExpression>MIT</PackageLicenseExpression>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <PackageReleaseNotes>Testing</PackageReleaseNotes>
    <PackageId>testme</PackageId>
    <Version>2.0.0</Version>
    <Authors>me</Authors>
    <Description>mytest</Description>
    <Copyright>company</Copyright>

 </PropertyGroup>
```

See [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#pack-target).

When I upload the nuget package on `nuget.org`,

[image]

[image]

**And** when I finish publishing it, I got it:

[image]

[image]

[image]